# C# NAudio Out of Memory Exception while working with large files

Tags: c#, arrays, naudio, zedgraph

```
NAudio.Wave.WaveChannel32 wave = new NAudio.Wave.WaveChannel32(new NAudio.Wave.WaveFileReader(open.FileName));         
byte[] mainBuffer = new byte[wave.Length];              
wave.Read(mainBuffer, 0, mainBuffer.Length);
```

I want to do some calculations and plot the waveform of a wav file using NAudio and ZedGraph. However when file is too large (greater than 100 megabyte) `wave.Read(mainBuffer, 0, mainBuffer.Length);`throws out of memory exception. How can i solve this issue? Pls can anyone help me?

I changed my code i will write here as soon as possible.

Comment: Here is the link to NAudio Source http://naudio.codeplex.com/documentation. You may find the resolution from there or ask from them.

Comment: That happens, a 100 megabyte hole in the address space can get tricky to find after a program has been running for a while.  You don't *really* want to have to plot a 100 MB worth of audio data, read only what you can reasonably display.  Or change the Platform target setting on your EXE project to AnyCPU.

Comment: How can an audio editor software handle problem like this? If i take the half of the data, i can't see a reasonable waveform. :/

Comment: I will try to use wave.BeginRead. I hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend against reading the whole file in one go. Read a few seconds at a time, calculate the peak values for your waveform plot and then move on to the next few seconds.

Comment: Should i use BeginRead method to do this or you suggest loops?

Comment: loops. If you're plotting the waveform, it will likely be only a few pixels at the most per second of audio, so read a second, calculate the peaks, and then read the next second etc